# How do I extract the integers of a number stored in float in exponential format?

Tags: c, precision

For example:

If I have a number saved as

```
float f = 1.23005979e-41;
```

I wanted to get the integral parts of it like

1 and 23005979

Comment: Transform into a string with `sprintf` and then parse the resulting string, possibly using `strtol`. 3-4 lines of code.

Comment: You need to be more specific with what you mean by "the integers of a number", because the numbers may not be very precise. They may be truncated. And in this very example, the integers `1` and `23005979` parts have very little to do with the floating point number. Without the exponent, these numbers mean nothing.

Comment: The answer to your question is "You don't." As soon as the assignment to `f` is performed, you lose some of the original digits. I realize that you have very cleverly chosen a subnormal number that actually can be stored as a `float`, and still retain the correct 8 digits after the decimal point. But that isn't going to happen in general.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Getting the “integer parts” of a floating-point number like this is almost never an appropriate thing to do. Explain what the purpose of this is so that people can put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 100

int main(){
    double f = 1.23005979e-41;
    char str[MAX_LENGTH];
    sprintf(str,"%g",f);
    char * part1 = strtok(str,".");
    char * part2 = strtok(NULL,".");
    printf("First part: %s\nSecond part: %s\n",part1,part2);
    char * e = strchr(part2,'e');
    *e = '\0';
    int p1 = (int) atof(part1);
    int p2 = (int) atof(part2);
    printf("First part: %d\nSecond part: %d\n",p1,p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `"."` as a delimiter for the second token, and then `strchr` for the `"e"`.

Comment: @Cheatah Simply and literally I answered the question! Considering the given number 1.23005979e-41.

Comment: I didn't say you didn't. It's just weird that you wouldn't use `strtok(NULL, "e")` for the second part.

Comment: @Cheatah I liked you !